# How do I trim DB field spaces querying DB with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, trim

In DB i have a field `PhoneNumber = '123 456 789'`

Query returns null:

```
return context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => с.PhoneNumber.Trim() == "123456789")
```

Is it possible to trim white spaces using EF?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a little detail: trim does not remove all white spaces, just leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: You could try `с.PhoneNumber.Replace(" ","") == "123456789"` but I don't know if it is supported by EF.

Comment: My bad, have to go back to school. But anyway, how do I trim it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.71).aspx) will only trim leading and trailing whitespace: -

*string.Trim() - Removes all occurrences of white space characters from the beginning and end of this instance.*

You could use:

```
string.Replace(" ", string.Empty):
```

Usage:

```
return context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => с.PhoneNumber.Replace(" ", string.Empty)) == "123456789")
```

Answer (score 3):

Trim removes leading and traling white-spaces only.

So you should try something like:

```
return context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => с.PhoneNumber.Replace(" ","") == "123456789")
```

By personal opinion, this way of filtering can higly affect performances on great data.
You should consider storing the numbers in your db already formatted without spaces.